# Find $\overline{mnp}$ such that $\overline{mnp}=4p(m+n)^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find $\overline{mnp}$ such that $\overline{mnp}=4p(m+n)^2$

---

I can show $p\in \{4;6\}$:

$2 \mid RHS \not=0 \implies p\in\{2;4;6;8\},\ (m+n)^2\in\{\overline{...1};\overline{...4};\overline{...6};\overline{...9}\}$, it is easy to show $p\in \{4;6\}$, but this way is pretty long. Any other way that better to show $p$ just can equal to $6$ and solve the problem (the answer is $\overline{mnp}=216$)

Comment: open $\overline {mnp}$ as $100m+10n+p$.

Comment: I tried that, what next ?

Answer (score 1):

If $p =4$, then

$100m+10n+4 = 16(m+n)^2$ is a multiple of $4$. Thus $n = 2l$.

$25m + 5l +1 = 4(m+2l)^2 = 4m^2 + 16ml + 16l^2 =RHS$, since $m,l$ cannot be $0$ at the same time. If $m =0$, then $5l+1 = 16l^2$, cannot be true. Thus $m\ge1$.

Then $l\neq 0$, otherwise $25m =4m^2$. So $4 \ge l\ge1$, $l$ cannot be 5, since $n =2l$.

Since if $m\ge 6$, $4m^2>25m,16ml>5l,16l^2>1$, contrdiction with the equality. Thus $1\le m\le 5$.

And $RHS$ is also a multiple of 4. Thus $m+l$ mod $4$ = 3.

We have $(m,l) = (1,2),(2,1),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2)$. And we may check them easily.

For p =6, it is done in the same way, but a little bit more complicated, but much faster.

Since

$100m+10n+6 = 24(m+n)^2$, thus

$$24m^2 +(48n-100)m+24n^2-10n-6 = 0$$

has a solution. Thus determinant

$$(48n-100)^2-4*24*(24n^2-10n-6) = 10024 - 9560n\ge 0$$
thus $n = 0$ or $n=1$. The rest is easy.

Comment: If for $p=4$, we use the same way as $p=6$, we can also get $n=0$ or $n=1$.